# Split on commas then sum numeric values one by one in C#

Tags: c#, list, split, sum, numeric

I have been trying to solve this problem for 3-4 hours and checked on internet many examples. I can split on commas; however, I cannot reach numeric values one by one and sum them.

```
var MyList = context.ProductAndPriceList();
```

I have string **MyList** and **MyList's** values like below,

```
"Apple,5"

"Computer,7"

"Mouse,12"
```

Result must be 5+7+12=**24**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving my answer as pseudo (c# based) code as I cannot tell which programming language you are using.
The Below code is untested but should not be far off correct for C# .Net and outlines the logic behind getting the result you want. I expect you are forgetting to convert the value you are getting from the split method into an integer before trying to add them up. When you split a string even though the result you get looks like 5 it is actually still "5" (a string) if that makes sense.

Edit: removed redundant code I noticed.

```
//Your list
var MyList = context.ProductAndPriceList(); 

//My variables
int total = 0;

foreach(string val in MyList){
    //Split your string to get the number (still as a String)
    string str_number = val.split(',')[1];
    //Convert the number string into an int variable
    int int_number = int.Parse(str_number);
    //Add this value to the total
    total += int_number;
}

//Display the total count in the console to check its working.
console.writeLine(total);
```